# Is there a Python module that detects and generates a regression type and curve equation for a set of data points?

Tags: python, numpy, regression

I am working on a research project that is attempting to generate a new day trading index for evaluation of short term cyclical changes in stock price and possibly make trades off of it. In order to do this, I need a Python module that can easily generate a regression equation for later evaluation in numpy. Is there a module that can do this for me?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
from scipy import stats
?stats.linregress()
```

docs here:
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html

Edit: example from the docs is nice and simple

```
x = np.random.random(10)
y = np.random.random(10)
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(x,y)
```